# Помогите сделать свой ToolBox/Вывод кнопок слева. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужна Ваша помощь! Не знаю как вывести список из кнопок слева, чтобы потом на форме можно было расположить различные элементы. (надеюсь понятно объяснил). То есть, при нажатии на 1 кнопку - выводит один список элементов с их возможностями, по нажатию на другую кнопку - другие... Пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: wpf? winforms? web?

Comment: Я использую Winforms.

Comment: Так почему в теги не добавили?

Comment: телепатией должны вам помогать? Конкретная технология меняет всё.

Comment: Не добавил, так как новенький, не подумал даже. Второе, я примерно предполагаю как сделать, но не уверен. Возможно, что нужно накидать все на одну форму, слева сделать кнопки, справа все остальное, делать Visible, а чтобы было удобнее в выборе элементов, выбирать каждый элемент, перекидывая его на передний план. Не уверен, что верно, хочу услышать мнение экспертов.

Comment: В рамках винформс считаю что это весьма нетривиальной задачей, разве что найти готовый компонент. В WPF - подобное делается относительно легко.

Comment: @srvr4vr, ну Win 10 Tweaker сделан на WinForms, так что... Плюс сделан он самоучкой. Не думаю, что это сложно, просто нужно понять принцип. Но, увы, у меня много всяких догадок, но я не уверен, что они верные. А так-то можно делать по-разному, конечно, каждый кодер - уникален.

Comment: Я не говорил, что это невозможно) И можно даже сделать относительно легко через адовые костыли. Закопайте уже труп винформсов, если надо что-то красивое и нестандартное - юзайте WPF